# Prove a function's nth derivative is bounded by a function iff its Fourier transformation is

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The space $S$ of functions on $R$ consists of smooth functions that satisfy for nonnegative integers $n$ and $r$
\begin{gather*}
\left| \frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n} \right| \leq C_{r,n}(1+x^2)^{-r}
\end{gather*}
for some constants $C_{r,n}$. Show that $f\in S$ if and only if its Fourier transform 
\begin{gather*}
(\hat{f})(x) = \int e^{ixy} f(y) dy \in S
\end{gather*}

I tried this: if $f\in S$, let $g(x) = \int e^{ixy} f(y) dy$, I want to prove $g \in S$ it is right. 
$$
|g^{(n)}(x)| = \left| \int (iy)^n e^{ixy} f(y) dy \right| \leq \int \left| y^n f(y)\right| dy \leq C_{r,n}  \int y^n (1+y^2)^{-r}dy
$$
I think I might get into some wrong direction here, and I don't know how to proceed. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your argument shows that  $\hat {f}$ and its derivatives are bounded. In order to show that $x^{n} \hat {f^{k}}$ is bounded use the fact that $(-ix)^{n} \hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f^{(n)}$ and that derivatives  of f are also in S.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry I still don't get it. Would you like to explain more and thank you!